# Amazon EC2 Deployment Not Working When IP Address Typed Into Browser Suspect Ngnix Problems

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am nearing the last step of deploying my Django app and I think I am having a Nginx problem. This is my first time deploying, so give me a break.

Basically, the problem is that when I navigate to my public IP on my browser I am getting a *webpage is not available error*.

I am thinking it is an issue with how I am writing out my directory structure in my Nginx configuration script, but am unsure. I am following a tutorial and don't really understand the script they are asking me to run.

***Here is my app's directory structure within my server...***

```
/home/ubuntu/flower_shop/flowershop
```

***Here is my Nginx's file that configures Nginx***

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 54.213.141.60;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off;}
    location /static/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/flower_shop/flowershop;
}
location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/flower_shop/flowershop/flowershop.sock;
}
```

***I am creating the above file by typing the following into my command line...***

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/flower_shop
```

Can you see anything obvious that I am doing wrong? `Gunicorn` is set up fine and my app works on my local host. I have tried restarting `Nginx`, but I get the same results.

Comment: Do you have the security group for this EC2 instance set to allow connections on port 80 from everywhere? Do you get a response if you try to telnet to port 80 of this host?

Comment: `proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ub...` isn't valid. it's either a unix proxy or a http proxy. Do you get anything in error logs? What's the status code that's returned? Are you working through an ELB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope you have done the following step:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/flower_shop /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flower_shop
```

Some other diagnostic commands which will help pin down the problem:

1. Supply nginx error and access logs
2. output of netstat -tulpn | grep nginx
3. In ssh session do curl -D - http://localhost:80
4. Try replacing the above snippet with the following extremely simple server config. Notice the only filtering it has for now is for port 80. It assumes your gunicorn is serving at 8080. Change port appropriately, if required.

```

```
server{
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    } 
}
```

```

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.